# 16.04 lightdm will not login one user, will login another

Tags: login, lightdm

User {D} had trouble with her laptop.  Would not start...  So I upgraded to 16.04 and installed a second user: {M}.  During the upgrade, {M} was made the admin user and {D} was re-instated as an admin user subsequently.  Now {M} can login fine.  {D} can login at a console (Ctrl+Alt+F2), but cannot login to lightdm: gets a blank screen and then back to login.  After having messed around deleting .Xauthority, reconfiguring lightdm, etc, etc, without success, I looked at the lightdm.log and found (somewhat editted):

```
Greeter start authentication for {D}
Session pid=2926: Started with service 'lightdm', username '{D}'
Session pid=2926: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
Session pid=2926: Sending SIGTERM
Session pid=2926: Terminated with signal 15
Session: Failed during authentication
Seat seat0: Session stopped
```

compared with:

```
Greeter start authentication for {M}
Session pid=3001: Started with service 'lightdm', username '{M}'
Session pid=3001: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
Continue authentication
Session pid=3001: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
Authenticate result for user {M}: Success
User {M} authorized
```

And the password used *is* correct, because when it isn't, one gets a little red message.  Obviously, there is something wrong with {D}'s setup and it was probably wrong before the upgrade, because she was already having trouble.  I've been through the lightdm .conf files and there doesn't seem to be anything unusual.  *accountsservice* is running on the system and it may be giving a bad response, but I don't know how to find/fix it.  Ideas anyone ?

Comment: The contents of user `{D}`'s `~/.xsession-errors` file might be helpful, as well

Comment: Possibly, but it details a crash that happened in November 2016:                   Script for ibus started at run_im.
    init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/susres.2016-11-09_16:55:05.673711.crash) main process (1991) terminated with status 1
    init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/susres.2016-11-06_09:43:46.889056.crash) main process (1988) terminated with status 1

Comment: Assuming they've been actively using their account since then, I wonder if their home dir is not where you think it is (perhaps due to a mount that's fallen off)? when you deleted their .Xauthority file, did you check its ownership / age / permissions? Did you verify that their home directory itself is writeable?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I checked /home and found that the user and directory names for {D} did not match.  Re-instating {D} following upgrade by using System settings/User Accounts added a new {D} and left the old one as #1000.  I've run chown down {D}'s home directory and got a successful logon.  Would still like to know how properly to re-instate a user, but that problem is now in the past.

Comment: Maybe you could write that up as an answer, for the record?